# How to calculate total file sizes from a new-line delimited list stored in variable?

Tags: bash, scripts, nemo

I'm trying to create a Nemo script that will calculate total file size of selected files and pass it on to the rest of the script.

It is using NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS environment variable that Nemo itself sets when some files are selected.

The problem is, the variable contains **a new line separeted paths and file names** and I don't know how to handle those.

Any ideas?

Edit: what I get if I echo the contents of the variable into a file is eg:
`/home/sasa/Pictures/1041247.png /home/sasa/Pictures/849611447.jpg /home/sasa/Pictures/IO2.jpg`

which looks more like space than new line delimited.

Comment: Can you post an example content of the variable? Hopefully with filenames that contain spaces and newlines.

Comment: Please edit the additional information into the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `du`:

```
du -c $(echo "$VAR")
```

---

This will not work when the file names contain spaces.

Use this:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
    du "$f";
done < <(echo "$VAR") \
| grep -o "^[0-9]*" \
| paste -sd+ | bc
```

Comment: RoVo, thanks a million! Though, I don't understand your magic with "read -r f" and slight discrepancy that always seems to creep in between what Nemo reports as total selected file size and your code eg https://ibb.co/eWv5Jy it still does the trick very well.

Comment: Nautilus seems to print "apparent size". `du` prints disk usage of file. See `man du` -> `--apparent-size`.

Comment: As a side note, it turns out that wc -c in instead of du returns file size that is exactly the same as reported by Nemo in file properties.